# What is the purposes of exe files in the MVC5 projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

In MVC5 Project there are 3 exe files:
[image]

My web-hosting provider is not letting me to publish exe files, and he told me to delete them.

During web-deploy I remove selection for this 3 files and publish the rest of the project.

When the publishing process finish and I try to access my website I got the error message that the csc.exe is missing :)

Can I do something to not publish exe files and also my website to run as expected?

Edit - I changed MVC4 with MVC5!

Edit - **I discuss with my web-hosting provider and he allowed me to read/write exe files and now my project is running as expected.**

Comment: MVC4 with roslyn? Some information is probably missing in your post... Regular VS2013 + MVC4 projects don't need that...

Comment: These are the Roslyn compilers. Their purpose is to compile code. For an ASP.NET project, I would expect that they compile views (written in Razor syntax, etc). In any case, they are included in the MVC template and obviously they are required. If your hosting provider advertises itself as an ASP.NET hosting service and doesn't know this, politely inform them. If they still don't change their policy, find another provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a comprehensive explanation here:
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/03/20/10-questions-10-answers-on-roslyn.aspx

And here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications.aspx

I got the sabe issue with exe files, so I've unnistalled it using the command prompt in the Visual Studio 2015:

```
uninstall-package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

After uninstalling this package, these "exe" files are not being created in the bin Folder anymore.